# Vue component to autocomplete an input

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, autocomplete, vue-component

There are a lot of autocomplete components to VueJS on the internet, but none that I found fit to my project.

I need a autocomplete component with the requisits:

- Able to use `v-model`;
- The list is just a suggestion. The input is free to type;
- The component is css customizable (I want to use a simple bootstrap design on it).

Can someone help me?

Comment: I voted to close this as off topic because stackoverflow isn't for suggestions on libraries/tools.  But even so, [vue-simple-suggest](https://github.com/KazanExpress/vue-simple-suggest) supports all those things.

Comment: You can use vuetify autocomplete https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes